# SQL and check with multiple strings

Tags: sql

I have a rule, Class must be:
Class           varchar(30)  gets by default 'Unclassified'; accepts only the following values: 'Unclassified', 'Nature', 'Family', 'Work', 'Travel', 'Misc'.

result must be like this:

```
CHECK(((class)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['Unclassified'::character varying, 'Nature'::character varying, 'Family'::character varying, 'Work'::character varying, 'Travel'::character varying, 'Misc'::character varying])::text[])))
```

How can I get it with check, multiple or clauses will not give the result.
So it must be something else than just `check(class = 'x,  .........)`

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using Postgres.

If you want a check constraint against a fixed list of values, you can just use `in`:

```
create table mytable(
    id serial primary key,
    class text 
        default 'Unclassified'
        check(class in ('Unclassified', 'Nature', 'Family', 'Work', 'Travel', 'Misc'))
);
```

Comment: Hi, it gives this with it, already tried:Database message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "check"
LINE 7:  check(class in ('Unclassified', 'Nature', 'Family', 'Work',...
         ^

Comment: @kasivitonen: which database are you using?

Comment: Viope world , it is high scool platforrom'so not sure

Comment: @kasivitonen: you will probably need to figure out what database they use. Your original syntax strongly suggested Postgres, hence my answer - but not all databases support check constraints, and the syntax may vary.

Comment: @kasivitonen: what does `select version();` give you? GMB's code is actually standard ANSI SQL and not specific to any database product.

Comment: I cannot use it, because my results will come in platform that has it own database build in. This is one part of my theory page, where i am learning the sql language:
CREATE TABLE Product (
   ProductID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   Name         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   TypeCode     VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
   Price        DECIMAL NOT NULL,
   Updated      DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
  
   CHECK (TypeCode NOT LIKE 'AB_A' AND TypeCode NOT LIKE 'B%'),
   CHECK (Price > 0),
   CHECK (ProductID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000 AND ProductID % 2 = 0) 
);

Comment: Hi again, thanks for help. I found this in my theory page:

TypeCode (a product type code or some similar) is checked against the LIKE expressions provided. For example, codes like ABBA or ABCA are not accepted for a reason or another. If we had a compact set of type codes available or in use, we could have written an IN clause to define that only this set of values is acceptable and others, if inserted, are to be discarded. This would ensure a product would not get an impossibe product code because of a typo, for example.

So it means that I should be enabled to use "in"